# Trying to use "with_items" and "when" in a Ansible playbook to clone a repo

Tags: ansible

Hello everyone and thanks for stepping by. As the title says, i'm trying to use those Ansible modules as follow. I want to clone a Wordpress repo depending if a variable is "yes" or "no".

This is my main Ansible playbook (using it with Vagrant through vagrant --provision). I'll provide just relevant parts.

```
vars:
  nginx_server_blocks:
  - { server_name: "dev.simple-site.io", document_root: "simple-site", wordpress: "no" }
  - { server_name: "dev.wordpress-site.io", document_root: "wordpress-site", wordpress: "yes" }
tasks:
 - name: clone Wordpress repo
   git: repo=git:https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git
        dest=/var/www/{{ item.document_root }}
   with_items: nginx_server_blocks
   when: item.wordpress == "yes"
```

When i run `vagrant provision`i get this error:

```
fatal: [default] => failed to parse: SUDO-SUCCESS-rtlizwskstbaxddabxlgqtxxqzambxnh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408592922.35-152092658109200/git", line 2119, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408592922.35-152092658109200/git", line 524, in main
    add_git_host_key(module, repo, accept_hostkey=module.params['accept_hostkey'])
File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408592922.35-152092658109200/git", line 1986, in add_git_host_key
fqdn = get_fqdn(module.params['repo'])
File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1408592922.35-152092658109200/git", line 2022, in get_fqdn
if "@" in result:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Any ideas of the error? i've google it and read the ansible docs about using `when`and `with_items`but no luck.

If helps, my host machine is a mac and the guest is ubuntu 14.04 through Vagrant. Ansible was installed via pip and it's 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
repo=git:https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git
```

to

```
repo=https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git
```

Ansible is seeing the git prefix and is expecting the syntax `git@github.com:Wordpress/Wordpress.git` which would also work if you want to use git-ssh.

Comment: Thanks! It worked just fine. Maybe i missunderstood the example at Ansible docs but with the adjustment now its working. Thank you @user24364!